# jQuery - How to pass multiple callback functions in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

In JS file have multiple ajax calls,so I would like to call one AJAX call with multiple callback functions.can any one help me how to call multiple AJAX calls.Here is test code,

```
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  dataType : 'json',
  success : test1(data)
});

$.ajax({
  url : url,
  dataType : 'json',
  success : test2(data)
});
```

It is working fine,can you please help me how we can call both ajax calls in one.

Comment: `success : test1(data)` and `success : test2(data)` cannot 'working fine' !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just call both of  your function inside one successs function...

```
 $.ajax({
   url : url,
   dataType : 'json',
   success : function(data){
      test1(data);
      test2(data);
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 14):

use the [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object returned by ajax

```
var a1 = $.ajax({ 
    url : url, 
    dataType : 'json', 
    success : test2
})
.done(cb1)
.done(cb2);
a1.done(cb3);
```

Comment: this is actually the best answer.

Comment: What happens when cb1 throws an exception?

Answer (score 3):

You can use as follow :

```
$.ajax({
      url : url,
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(data){
                if(url=="xyz.php")
                     test2(data);
                else if(url=="abc.php")
                     test1(data);

      } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
$.ajax({
      url : url,
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(data){
            test2(data);
            test1(data);
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so

```
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function( data ) {
     test1(data);
     test2(data);
  }
});
```

Simples.

Or to go a step further if you want all the arguments you can do this

```
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function() {
     test1.apply(null, arguments);
     test2.apply(null, arguments);
  }
});
```

The you can use them like this

```
var test2 = function( data, status, jqXHR) {
    console.log( data, status, jqXHR );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily define one callback function in which you would call multiple ones.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: myGlobalCallback(data) 
});

function myGlobalCallback(data) {
    cb1(data); 
    cb2(data);     
}
```

Comment: You are not waiting the success event to happen to call myGlobalCallback function, and BTW, when success is fired, you use returned function value, if any which is not the case here. In fact, as data is undefined, this will bring an error. You want: `success: myGlobalCallback`